# Symfony2. Howto multiple config files in a bundle

Tags: symfony, config

I just can't figure this out.

I am writing a report builder in Symfony2.

I have a config file like this:

```
bundle:
  sections:
    Report1:
      buckets:
        bucket1:
        ...
      calculations:
        calculation1:
        ...
      report:
        rows:
          row1:
          ...
```

For several reports, this gets to be loooong.

I've tried breaking this file into smaller files and loading them separately.  This didn't work.  Here's what I tried:

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('bundle_report.yml');
    $loader->load('bundle_report_1.yml');  // Order is important here
    $loader->load('bundle_report_2.yml');
    $loader->load('bundle_report_3.yml');
    $loader->load('services.yml');
}
```

What's the best way to do this?  Is it even possible?

The error I'm getting is (exception is thrown before $loader->load()s happen):

```
The child node "sections" at path "bundle" must be configured
```

If I switch the order ( $loader->load()s first, then new Configuration()):

```
 There is no extension able to load the configuration for "bundle"
```

Configuration looks like this:

```
public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
{
    $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
    $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('bundle');

    $rootNode
        ->children()
            ->arrayNode('sections')->isRequired()
                ->prototype('array')
                ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not supposed to load your config files from the load method.
This is made to

- load the base config from Configuration class
- compare it to custom config (yml files in app/config/)
- and load the bundle services

All your config files must be in **app/config/** to be passed as parameters to the load method. As you do it here, they are useless.
That's why you get

```
The child node "sections" at path "bundle" must be configured
```

And if you reports are evolving, maybe it's better to put this in a business logic (model/entities) and to plug an admin (eg: sonata admin).

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did.

1. Loaded it all into one 'bundle.yml' config file.
2. Put that file in app/config
3. Imported it in app/config.yml imports section
4. Defined the 'Configuration' class in my bundle (see above).  Bundle generator created this.
5. Then, in my BundleReportExtension class, added these lines

   ```
   // Parse our configuration.  It's included in /app/config/config.yml
   // Parser is Configuration class in this package.
   $configuration = new Configuration();
   $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

   // Great.  Parsed.  Now copy to parameters for later use.
   $container->setParameter('bundle.default_config', $config['default_config']);
   $container->setParameter('bundle.sections', $config['sections']);
   ```

Now, I can't get the configuration as an array with:

```
    $container->setParameter('bundle.sections');
```

In much searching this is the best I could come up with.  If you have other suggestions, please share.